# Как узнать Mac адрес пользователя?

Tags: php, linux

Можно ли как-нибудь узнать Mac адрес пользователя, который соединился к Linux серверу или же посредством php? Есть идеи?

Answer (score 5):

Если вкратце - это невозможно.

Comment: ) я примерно тоже самое написал))

Answer (score 3):

MAC адрес можно узнать только в рамках одного физического сегмента сети.
В любом случае MAC виден не дальше ближайшег роутера.

Comment: Узнать Mac внутри сети, есть же возможность узнать IP адрес по средством php, а затем вычислить Mac по IP средством какой нибудь linux команды.

Comment: http://srcboard.com/537mdl

Comment: Да я тоже только, что нашел подобное... уже в голову пришло как даже...

Comment: @Фарход: ARP, который вы имеете в виду, что, по вашему, должен на весь интернет бродкастом кричать? Короче, IP->MAC вне своей сети вы не сделаете никак.

Comment: Ну а если внутри сети, то да, пожалуйста. Нужная вам команда — arp.

Answer (score 3):

Я уже нашел решение, но оно работает строго если этот пользователя внутри твоей сети.
через php получаешь его IP адрес за тем отправляете команду линуксу по средством php "cat /proc/net/arp" таким кодом:

```
$d=passthru("cat /proc/net/arp");
```

получены ответ уже парсируете.
Вот примерный ответ:

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
94.199.16.161    0x1         0x2         00:0f:e2:61:24:f1     *        eth0
```

Авось кому пригодиться. Всем большое спасибо за наводки.

Answer (score 2):

```
function definition_mac() {

 if(PHP_OS == 'Linux'){  $macAddr = exec("grep ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." /proc/net/arp | awk '{print $4}'");  }
 elseif(PHP_OS == 'WINNT'){

  $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $macAddr=false;
  $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
  $lines=explode("\n", $arp);

  foreach($lines as $line){
    $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
    if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress){ $macAddr=$cols[1]; }
  }
 };
 return $macAddr; 
};
// Выводит MAC-адрес. Работает только в локальной сети.
```